# Getting the location in Android programatically

Tags: android, location

I know this has been asked a ton, so my apologies. I have the following code, and cannot get the location, always a null response. I am trying to avoid a LocationListener in this instance because I am already using an update Service, and the location really doesn't have to be that fine, so the last known location is good enough. Thanks for the help.

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
String providers[] = {"gps", "network", "passive"};
Location loc = null;
for(String x : providers) {  
    loc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(x);
    if(loc != null) break;  
}
if(loc != null) {
    // do something, never reached
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following code, and cannot get the location, always a null response.

Of course.

> I am trying to avoid a LocationListener in this instance because I am already using an update Service

I have no idea what this means, but I suspect that you will need a `LocationListener` whether you like it or not.

Android is not constantly checking your location. Particularly with GPS, that would be horrible for the battery. Android only checks your location when somebody is using `requestLocationUpdates()` or `addProximityAlert()`.

Comment: If that is true, what is the point of the getLastKnownLocation() function? Thats all I really want, the last known location from any service, precision is not a big deal. Also, with listeners, I would have to make a listener for each provider, and that seems a huge waste since I am only updating every 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but maybe this happens because you use an emulator?
I remember I've tried to check last known location and have something like yours error.
So I always check getLastKnownLocation(provider) != null before use it.